# NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

Am encountering this error in Windows Command line,done a wide search but could not get a perfect answer.Please find the error below and help in solving.

```
python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
>>>
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: How are you getting this traceback? What did you input? I'm guessing that you tried to do `python` which starts the interpreter and then typing `python` again, which is interpreted as a variable name.

Comment: you did not include the `>>>` before the word 'python', right?

Answer (score 47):

It looks like you are trying to start the Python interpreter by running the command `python`.

However the interpreter is already started. It is interpreting `python` as a name of a variable, and that name is not defined.

Try this instead and you should hopefully see that your Python installation is working as expected:

```
print("Hello world!")
```

Comment: This when typed worked out well but when i type as just "python it is  showing up the error as name error:python not defined.What does this signify?>>> print ("hello world")
hello world
>>>

Answer (score 21):

When you run the Windows Command Prompt, and type in `python`, it starts the Python interpreter.

Typing it again tries to interpret `python` as a variable, which doesn't exist and thus won't work:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\USER>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
>>> print("interpreter has started")
interpreter has started
>>> quit() # leave the interpreter, and go back to the command line

C:\Users\USER>
```

If you're not doing this from the command line, and instead running the Python interpreter (python.exe or IDLE's shell) directly, you are not in the Windows Command Line, and `python` is interpreted as a variable, which you have not defined.

Comment: probably he didn't run the command line at all, but the python interpreter directly.