# python command-line error ('python' is not defined)

Tags: python

I am very new to programming with python. (I am using Windows 10)

So I recently installed Python 3.5.2 and I am trying to write a simple command in the python command line (name of program: Python 3.5):

```
python -h
```

What I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "$stdin$", line 1, in  NameError: name 'python' is not
>   defined

($ = <> by the way)

When I run it in CMD it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Refer this link, it should be the same issue you're facing: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857105/nameerror-name-python-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks for the help I get it now but how do I run the -h command in the python environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type in your program and then the command, for example `$ ./example.py [-h]`. You can also use `-?` or `--help` instead of `-h`

EDIT: In command line,

```
    $./programName.py [-h] -z
```

It should show you an error saying that `-z` is not recognized

Comment: what is the easiest command I can use so that I can see it works properly? (I have not created a file so that I can test this since this is the syntax)

Comment: You can use the sample `"hello world"` startup program. Just save it and do the rest of it, replacing the 'programName' with whatever you saved it as.

Comment: This link should you help you even more: [Command Line](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-command-line-arguments-argv-example/)