# Python not installing packages with pip

Tags: python, pip, package

I've had a look around, and cannot find an answer to my problem.

All I try to run is

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

but in just about everything I run, I get "invalid syntax" or

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    NameError: name 'python' is not defined

All I am trying to do is install a set of packages from a text file in a folder on my desktop.

This is stressing me, as nothing seems to work.

Id appreciate any help!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying `pip3 install` in a python shell instead of an OS shell

Comment: Please paste the error you received!

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. There are a number of common beginner problems which could manifest as this problem, but without anything concrete to show the context of the problem, we can't guess which is yours, and it doesn't make sense to just enumerate them all (googling for the error should give you a good sample). Show us *exactly* what you are doing and *exactly* the full error message you get as a result. See also the guidance for creating a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance type [python in before running that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857105/nameerror-name-python-is-not-defined), if you did then it's throwing that traceback call because it thinks `python` is a variable, not a command
Also, did you already try installing the package directly from the source?
Most can be run as `pip3.x install package` where package is the name of what you want to install (e.g Pygame). 
I would open a new command shell, terminate processes on current, and run
`python -v` to know the exact version you have installed. Then pip2.x or pip3.x (where x is version of 2 or 3) install package directly online.