# My Python shells and terminal in macOS don't allow me to ask the version type as 'python --version'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, pip

This is the resulting notice of entering "python --version"

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'python' is not defined

I have tried Python 2.7 and 3.6 shell as well as my terminal but cannot seem to figure out whats wrong.

Eventually, I am trying to get pip.

Comment: Can you share the terminal output of "python --version" ?

Comment: That is output from Python, not from your shell. You can't run `python --version` inside Python itself.

Comment: Also, if you are in python shell, the version getting is : `import sys; print(sys.version_info[:])`

Comment: python has a similar result

Comment: the terminal output of 'python --version' is the notice in the description

Comment: where is my shell?

Comment: @DavidFasos https://superuser.com/questions/178735/how-do-you-get-a-shell-on-a-mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: name 'python' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857105/nameerror-name-python-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

You habe to start a normal command line, not the python shell if you want that the command `python --version` works.

If you want to use the python shell you have to type

```
import sys
sys.version_info
```