# Python fails silently

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am trying to get started with Python, so I installed Python 3.8, from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) (on Windows 10). I remembered to check the "Add to PATH" during the installation and I have confirmed that it has been added to path, as seen in the first image.

However, when I try to use any commands, whether it be `python --version` or `python HelloWorld.py`, nothing happens. I have tried both the traditional command line as well as Powershell. I have also tried replacing `python` with `python3`, the result is the same. As you can see in the second image, I get no errors, just a blank line. So it's not that it cannot find Python at all, it rather seems that something is wrong with the installation.

Have anyone else encountered this kind of behavior? I have tried re-installing Python as well as removing old installations.

[image: The content of PATH]

*Image 1: Python seems to be correctly added to PATH.*

[image: Pythons missing error message]

*Image 2: Python fails to return any output. But also no error. Same thing happens with* `python HelloWorld.py`.

**Update 1** - Here is what I have tried so far:

- Changing PATH to refer directly to exe file.
- Using both Command Prompt and PowerShell.
- Rebooting the PC.
- Re-installing Python (including removing old versions).
- Both the `python` and `python3` command.

**Update 2** - NameError: name 'python' is not defined

*Update on the update: This was a wild goose chase. You are not supposed to be able to use that command in the interpreter, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857105/nameerror-name-python-is-not-defined).*

So I tried to use the console from the python.exe file instead, and I got the following answer. However, from what I can find on it, it's normally a problem you encounter on elements of the code (like `print()`) and not on the `python` command...?

(image removed)

**Update 3** - It works (kinda)
If I use the command `py --version` or `py test.py` it works. I have no clue why though...

Comment: Which code it returns with? (exit status)

Comment: Close the command prompt and try that same thing in a new instance of the command prompt.

Comment: Also are you on a 32-bit system? I see you have the 32-bit version installed.

Comment: @deathangel908 I do not see any returns anywhere. Does it log it somehow?

Comment: Does it also happen if you use the full path to `python.exe`, instead of just `python`?

Comment: @Jortega I have tried new instances of both Command Prompt and Powershell, without luck.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse My system is 64-bit. But I couldn't seem to find any 64-bit version of Python.

Comment: @zvone I have tried that as well, the result remains the same :-(

Comment: @Noceo Use the ones with a `-64`. I would uninstall python before installing the 64-bit version. You want the one that says: [Windows x86-64 executable installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/)

Comment: I have added another update to the post, where I actually get an error...

Comment: @Noceo It already shows the version up there. I think `python —version` should be run in cmd anyway, not the interpreter.

Comment: @Noceo Have you tried restarting your computer yet?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile you are right, that command is not allowed in the interpreter. However, the interpreter seems to work...

Comment: @Noceo That’s great then, no?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile both yes and no. It still kinda sucks, if I cannot use Command Prompt or Power Shell to run my programs.

Comment: See update 3. I got it to work with `py` (instead of `python`). I don't know why though.

Comment: @Noceo Is `HelloWorld.py` just meant to print “Hello world”?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile ye, for a start. It was just to test if I could run .py files.

Comment: For most recent Python, the installer only optionally adds `python` to the PATH (are you sure you selected this option when you reinstalled?), but also adds the Python Launcher application, `py`. The launcher application can be more useful because it lets you access multiple versions. https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable

Comment: @Stuart I checked the path at every installation, and its there. Also, if it wasn't in path, i guess i would get an actual error...

Comment: Oh, so it's still failing silently. Check if there are any other python distributions on your computer that it might be accessing?

Answer (score 1):

After extensive research, I still cannot find an answer to my own question. But I have found a work around, which minimizes the consequences:

Instead of using `python`, simply use `py`.

This will invoke the Python launcher instead of Python itself (from what I've read). For most people this will be good enough, but it is not the same. So it might cause issues and version mismatch in certain scenarios.

Also, despite of this weird behavior, Python seems to run fine in Visual Studio Code, when using the "Run" button (or the `py` command in the terminal).

Comment: Solution that solved my months-long problem!  Thanks to you!