# Can't import openCV in anaconda Python 3.10

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I installed openCV onto Python 3.10 and it's erroring in the import stage.

Any ideas on what to try for this?

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

>>> ^Z


(myenv) C:\Users\Eli Rogers>python -V
Python 3.10.6
```

Comment: your anaconda is broken. remove everything, reinstall everything. and make sure you know in what ("virtual") environment you're currently in, or avoid those entirely.

Comment: Thanks Christoph. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling conda (i even wiped windows and reinstalled it). Now I get this error when the install finishes

Package ecdsa conflicts for:
paramiko -> ecdsa[version='>=0.11,<2.0']
spyder -> paramiko -> ecdsa[version='>=0.11,<2.0']

Package comtypes conflicts for:
anaconda==2022.05 -> comtypes==1.1.10[build='py37haa95532_1002|py39haa95532_1002|py38haa95532_1002']
xlwings -> comtypes

Package scikit-image conflicts for:
anaconda==2022.05 -> scikit-image==0.19.2[build='py37hf11a4ad_0|py39hf11a4ad_0|py38hf11a4ad_0']
datashader -> scikit-image

Answer (score -1):

Here you are getting error because the interpreter has already started and when you have retype the python it is interpreting it as a variable so .

you can check out this :
[NameError: name 'python' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857105/nameerror-name-python-is-not-defined)

where the same problem has discussed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that wasn't the problem, I was just trying to show the version of python installed for your information.

The line where I get the error is this one:

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.